# Getting fatal error in drupal when open the site

Tags: views, 7

I am working on a site in which it was perfectly, but now its given this error

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/.../includes/sites/all/modules/context/plugins/context_condition_sitewide.inc'
>   (include_path='.:') in /var/www/.../includes/bootstrap.inc on line
>   3139.

Here we can see the path is changed `.../includes/sites/.....` where as the "include" and "sites" are on root folder.

So please guide me that how to solve this issue.

Comment: What did you change before the error occured? Did you remove or move files?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module using drush en "context".

Your site is not get `/context_condition_sitewide.inc` file or you may be accidently delete this module without disabling it from module list. Try reinstalling this module again.

Comment: I solve this error, just remove every folders and reupload the files on server...this error cause due to remove or move files.